# Mulitple canvas-images (by Chart.js) with toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js, todataurl

**How to handle two or more linked Canvas-Charts with [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)?** With this script the canvas-image is linked with a bigger version to present the big file in a fancybox or just two download it (right-click -> save). Easy.

```
<a HREF="#" id="canvas_link_1">
<canvas id="image1"></canvas>
</a>

<a HREF="#" id="canvas_link_2">
<canvas id="image2"></canvas>
</a>
```

To use *toDataURL()* with *Chart.js* it's a bit tricky, cause it will render the whole chart not before the animation has ended. If we do ask for the URL too early, it will present an empty (transparent) image. That's why we need *onAnimationComplete* in the options:

```
var options = { 
onAnimationComplete: done
}
```

Later in the script, it will fire/change the new HREF, when the animation is over.

```
var ct1 = document.getElementById("image1").getContext("2d");
ct1.canvas.width = document.getElementById("image1").offsetWidth;
ct1.canvas.height = document.getElementById("image1").offsetHeight;
var Chart1  = new Chart(ct1).Line(lineChartData1,options);

function done() {
var url1=document.getElementById("image1").toDataURL();
document.getElementById("canvas_link_1").href=url1;
}

var ct2 = document.getElementById("image2").getContext("2d");
ct2.canvas.width = document.getElementById("image2").offsetWidth;
ct2.canvas.height = document.getElementById("image2").offsetHeight;
var Chart2  = new Chart(ct2).Line(lineChartData2,options);

function done() {
var url2=document.getElementById("image2").toDataURL();
document.getElementById("canvas_link_2").href=url2;
}
```

That works. But only with **one** canvas-image. If I delete the 2nd *function done()* it will work with the 1st canvas, if I delete the 1st function, only the 2nd canvas presents the url.

I think the problem is with "done", it's not a name, just like a situation, or? The "var options" is are general for all canvas-images (for sure I can change to options1 and options2 and also to "Line(lineChartData1,options1)" but without any change)... so "done" will fire all *functions* and - that's bad - appearently only the last *function*.

On the other side I cannot rename the entry of *onAnimationComplete*. It's null or done, nothing else. What is to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have different callbacks with different names. "done" is just an example name (a better name would probably be "completed").

For example - first create two option objects, one for each chart:

```
var options1 = { 
    onAnimationComplete: done1
};

var options2 = { 
    onAnimationComplete: done2
};
```

Then initialize the charts with those:

```
...
var Chart1  = new Chart(ct1).Line(lineChartData1, options1);

...
var Chart2  = new Chart(ct2).Line(lineChartData2, options2);
```

And finally define the callbacks:

```
function done1() {
    var url = document.getElementById("image1").toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("canvas_link_1").href = url;
}

function done2() {
    var url = document.getElementById("image2").toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("canvas_link_2").href = url;
}
```

Hope this helps (and that I understood the problem correctly) !

Comment: Awesome, yes, it fixes the problem! Thank you very much. Maybe one additional question (may I should start a new thread?): The link leads to a bigger version of the canvas. In my script above, toDataURL (for HREF) will generate the "same" as in the canvas-element. But for the link I'd like to have a different "ct1.canvas.width" and "ct1.canvas.height".

Comment: @user3520414 the toDataURL will always use the current size of the canvas so the only way is to increase the size of the canvas. If this becomes a problem layout-wise you could use CSS to force the one canvas down to the display size while retaining a bitmap size which you want/need.